# Keep floating div centered on window resize css

Tags: html, css

Can we center a floating div within a div on window resize only using CSS?

My container div is 100% width and it contains 3 divs inside with fixed widths.
I need to center the inside divs on window resize.

Is there any way to do this with **only using CSS**?

Comment: You can do it. But without floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would help if you post some code. But blindly I would suggest you set your `div`s to `display: inline-block` and add `text-align: center` to the parent container.

Example HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>    
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Example CSS

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.box{
  background: red; //random value
  height: 100px;  //random value
  width: 100px; //random value
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2wobyt8s/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a couple different ways:

- the three divs could be floated have a width of 33.333%
- the container div could be set to `display:table` and the contained divs be set to `display:table-cell`.